# Auto-Stretching UITextField on typing

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uitextfield, uilabel

I have a `UITextField` that I created programatically. I want to have uneditable prefixed characters on the beginning and end, such as

```
"Hello [TextField] world".
```

First, I tried adding characters manually and with using `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` make but this approach won't work because if the user long press on the TextField and come to beginning, he can edit the first characters (so can mess the prefixed characters). This option didn't seem so convenient.

---

Another option could be creating an empty `UITextField`, and 2 static `UILabels` (for "Hello" and "world"). Here, another problem arises. As my `UITextField`'s text is center aligned (and vertically centered in the view), I was giving it a width of the view and 0 for x-axis (so textField touches both left and right edges of the view). Instead, if I try to give the TextField a fixed width while creating, the width doesn't expand/stretch as user types in.

What I want to achieve is starting width of TextField from 0, and having static `UILabel`s on each sides like `"hello "[textField]" world"`; as user types in, increasing/stretching the textField's width to both left and right (as it's textaligned center). And as the textField's width stretches, push `UILabel`'s towards the edge.. So:

```
|          ["Hello "][textField][" world"]         |

|    ["Hello "][MyTextFieldTextIsNice][" world"]   |
```

What is the proper way of achieving it without using Storyboard and programatically instantiating `UITextField` and `UILabel`s? How can I create auto-resizing textField as user types in that pushes the UILabels on the sides?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this kind of situation,Using `Storyboard` and both side of `UITextField` use `UILabel` with center alignment.

Below is the screenshot of `storyboard`.

[image]

Then I am doing delegate of the `UITextField` and uses following code.

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

    NSString *strForWholeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",textField.text,string];

    CGSize fontSize = [strForWholeString sizeWithAttributes:
                       @{NSFontAttributeName:
                             [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14]}];



    if (self.textfieldLayoutWidthConstraint.constant >= 40) {
        self.textfieldLayoutWidthConstraint.constant = fontSize.width + 40 ;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

**Swift Code**

```
func textField(textField: UITextField!, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String!) -> Bool {

        let strForWholeString = NSString(format:"%@%@", textField.text!,string) as String

        let fontSize: CGSize = strForWholeString.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0)])

        if self.textfieldLayoutWidthConstraint?.constant >= 40 {
            self.textfieldLayoutWidthConstraint!.constant = fontSize.width + 40 ;
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded();
            self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints();
        }
        return true
    }
```

May this helps lot.

[You can download the sample code from here - Objective c](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxVigM97JuzCN28yb3QtUktSeWM)

[You can download the sample code from here - Swift](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxVigM97JuzCMkl0cS1hZ09OdGM)

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do this without making outlet of width constraint ?

Comment: @Irfan you need to check character like wise `Jonas` answer.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done but will take a little work. You would need to handle the `UITextFieldDelegate` and use a width constraints. You can achieve it by following the outline.

1. Your controller should adopt the UITextFieldDelegate and use this method to examine the length of the string the user is entering in `UITextField`:

   (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textFieldshouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
2. Based on the length of the string dynamically adjust the width constraint on the `UITextField`.
3. If you also set your constraints for the other labels on either side like so, it should behave as you expect. `@"[Label][UITextField][Label]"`.
4. You would also set a constraint on the UITextField to align it with CenterX of its parent view.

Examine the Text field entered, like so:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    // This is the string the user entered. Get the string and use string metrics
    // to figure out how long the string will be based on font and 
    // font size and adjust the width constraint on the UITextField
    // accordingly.
    return YES;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks @Cliff. I think this a better way than Jonas's answer, however I got a bit confused on your point 2 and 3. Can you please make a dummy sample project showing your way? I'd be very very grateful..

Comment: Yes it is better, it is the correct way to do it. I'm not going to write your program for you but I will expand slightly.

Comment: I'd be grateful if you expand it too. Surely, it will give me a spark to understand

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that you can add text to the textfield that is uneditable, but what you can do is automatically check the entered text and prepend "Hello" and append "world".

You would first have to check the entered text. You could do that like so:

```
var charArray: [Character] = []

for character in textField.characters {
charArray.append(character) }
```

This will give you an array of characters. You can then check whether the first characters are still "Hello " and whether the last ones are still " world":

```
func checkInputStartsHello() -> Bool {

guard charArray[0] == "H" else { return false }
guard charArray[1] == "e" else { return false }
guard charArray[2] == "l" else { return false }
guard charArray[3] == "l" else { return false }
guard charArray[4] == "o" else { return false }
guard charArray[5] == " " else { return false }

return true
}

func checkInputEndsWorld() -> Bool {

guard charArray[charArray.count - 1] == "d" else { return false }
guard charArray[charArray.count - 2] == "l" else { return false }
guard charArray[charArray.count - 3] == "r" else { return false }
guard charArray[charArray.count - 4] == "o" else { return false }
guard charArray[charArray.count - 5] == "w" else { return false }
guard charArray[charArray.count - 6] == " " else { return false }

return true
}
```

Then add "Hello " and " world" if these are false:

```
if !checkInputStartsHello() { textField.text = "Hello " + textField.text }
if !checkInputEndsWorld() { textField.text = textField.text + " world" }
```

Make sure to update the charArray every time text is entered and recheck the textField.text.

The result of this code will be a textfield that automatically shows the beginning and endings you give it right after the user clicks 'done' on the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `leftview` and `righttview` of textfield. for example,

```
 UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 40)]; 

 // create one label and add it to padding view and then set that padding as left view   

datePickerField.leftView = paddingView;  //here datepicker field is my textfield
datePickerField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

likewise you can do for rightview.

create label and paddingview as per required frame then add that label to padding view and set that paddingview as `leftview` or `rightview` of textfield.

So, it will automatically change their positions and size as textfield change.

Hope this will help :)